# Integration ( Area of a shaded region )

Tags: calculus, integration

I got stuck on this question for quite some time but I still can't get my head around it especially for question b). Please help.

[image: The Graph]

The curve $C$, shown in Figure 2, has equation $y = 3x – x^2$ It passes through the origin $O$ and the point $B$ on the $x$-axis.
a) Find the coordinates of the point $B$.
The shaded region $R$ is bounded by the curve and the line $AB$.
b) Find, by integration, the area of $R$.

Comment: I've done the first part of the question but got can't seem to get a grip on the second part.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

$x_B$ can be found by solving $3x-x^2=0$. Now you can work out the area of the right triangle colored red in the figure.

Now the area of the shaded region can be represented as

$$A=\int_{x_A}^{x_B} 3x-x^2\,dx-\text{area of the triangle}$$

[image]

Comment: That's what I thought to do exactly but I wasn't so sure if that was a triangle or not. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

Solve for $B$, where the line $AB$ intersects the x-axis by solving for $$3x-x^2 = 0 \iff -x(x -3) = 0 \iff x = 0,\text{ or } x = 3$$ $B$ must be the point $(3, 0)$, since when $x= 0$, we are at the origin.

Now, find the equation of the line $AB$: we have two points on the line, and can find the equation of the line using $$y = \dfrac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}\cdot x \iff y = \frac {0-2}{3-1}x = -x$$

Then, your integral is $$\int_1^3 (\text{upper curve - lower curve})\,dx$$ $$=\int_1^3 ((3x-x^2) - (-x)) \,dx = \int_1^3 4x-x^2\,dx$$